# Xampp is bringing apache and mysql not found when i run the control exe

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, xampp

I have been using xampp for a while and suddenly it brings error for apache and mysql:

"Apache or mysql shutdown unexpectedly This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues. If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums". A second attempt to retry will bring "apache/mysql not found".

I check both apache and mysql bin folder and i notice it removes httpd.exe and mysqld.exe this files automatically for some reason. I have tried several troubleshooting like un-installing and re-installing completely but its all been futile.

I manage to tweak it by creating a cmd file that copies this files (httpd.exe and mysqld.exe) where they are needed in xampp folder before i run xampp which seems to be working fine but i believe it shouldnt be so and i need to find out the reasons this files get removed on my pc. Any help and suggestions is highly welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

check any third party antivirus software?
Kaspersky Enterprise v10 killed my WAMP installation on win10 a few months back...

Bit more complicated but ...
if that does not fix it, you can run disk mon.. a Microsoft tool, wait for it to happen again an find the process ID in the disk mon log, that matches your file and look for the process in task manager to see what program did the delete...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/diskmon